# Pentaho - CSV Input not understanding special character [Windows to Linux]

Tags: linux, pentaho, transformation, business-intelligence, pdi

I have a transformation on Pentaho Data Integration where the first thing I do is I use the "CSV Input" to map my flat file.

I've never had a problem with it on windows, but now I'm chaning my server that spoon is going to run to a linux server and now I'm having problems with special characters.

The first thing I noticed was that my tables where being updated because the system was understanding the names as diferent strings to the ones that are at my database.

Checking for the problem, I also noticed that if I go to my "CSV Input" -> Preview, it will show me the preview of my data with the problem above:

[Special characters are not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwI4Z.png).

Where it should be:

```
Diretoria de Suporte à Decisão e Aplicação
```

I used a command to checked my file charset/codification and it showed:

```
$ file -bi foo.csv
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

If I open foo.csv on vi, it understands the special characters.

Any idea on what could be the problem or what should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any data files with this encoding, so you'll have to do some experimenting, but there are some steps designed to deal with these issues.

First, the `CSV Input` step has a field that allows you to select the encoding of the source file. The `Text File Input` step has both a "Format" (meaning line terminator) and "Encoding" selector under the "Content" tab.

In Transforms, you have the `Change file encoding` step under the Utility tab. This step is designed to copy many files while changing their encoding; that's why it's in a transform.

In Jobs, there's the `Convert file between Windows and Unix` step under the File Management tab, but this appears to only deal with line terminators.

Either way it appears if the CSV/Text file input steps don't suit your needs, you'll have to copy the file to a new encoding before reading it in. It will probably be easiest to try handling it with the file input steps first.

Comment: I changed the "File Encoding" field of my CSV Input to ISO-8859-1 and it worked for me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue reading a utf-8 encoded csv file on ubuntu box with pentaho 8.3.  All indications are the file is UTF-8 encoded both on windows and on the ubuntu box.  The step worked fine on Windows.  Don't know if the encoding got messed up during curl step or if there is a problem on the Ubuntu box or a bug in Pentaho.  So I found a total end-run workaround.  I URL encode the field with special characters before sending it to the server and then decoded the field in a javascript step with decodeURI.